# Ampersand in link description text?

Tags: php, urlencode

I am validating my site using http://validator.w3.org and have an issue where there is an `&` in my link description text.

This is taken from the source:

```
<a class='tag' href='/php/iphone software.php?function=developer&amp;dev=witch%26wizards+inc.&amp;store=143441'>witch&wizards inc.</a>
```

This gives this error in the validator:

> Line 188, Column 540: cannot generate system identifier for general entity "wizards"
>
> …6wizards+inc.&store=143441'>witch&wizards inc.
>
> ✉ An entity reference was found in the document, but there is no reference by that name defined

If I urlencode the description then the validation passes, but the user then sees the text displayed urlencoded, ie

> Developer witch%26wizards+inc.

However, I believe it's much more user friendly if this was displayed unencoded, ie

> Developer witch&wizards inc.

Is there a way to pass validation, but still have user friendly text displayed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple:

For ampersands as part of query string **values**, URL encode them to `%26`.

For displaying ampersands as text, or ampersands used to separate query string **key-value pairs** — in other words, for almost everything else — HTML encode them to their entities `&amp;`.

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<a class='tag' href='/php/iphone%20software.php?function=developer&amp;dev=witch%26wizards+inc.&amp;store=143441'>witch&amp;wizards inc.</a>
```

Comment: I am reading the developer string from a database and have tried using rawurlencode($developer); but that encodes it as %26, what can I use to encode it as &amp;

Comment: @kitenski: `htmlspecialchars($developer)`, or `str_replace('&', '&amp;', $developer)`.

Comment: `str_replace('&', '&amp;', $developer)` is absolutely hideous and you should not recommend it to beginners. o_O

Answer (score 2):

Try using `&amp;` rather than `%26`

EDIT: woah, &amp; is expanded on SO.

Comment: Try using it where? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Encode `&` in the URL as `%26`, not as `&amp;` (also encode the space as `%20`) and encode the `&` in the displayed text as `&amp;`:

```
<a class='tag' href='/php/iphone%20software.php?function=developer%26dev=witch%26wizards+inc.%26store=143441'>witch&amp;wizards inc.</a>
```

Note that there is a difference between [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) which are used to encode URLS and [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) used to encode displayed text in HTML. For example, if you wanted to display the text `<br/>` in HTML you would encode it as `&lt;br/&gt;`, but in a URL it would be `%3Cbr%2F%3E`.

Use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to encode special characters as HTML entities in PHP.

Comment: It's a problem in the link text ie >witch&wizards inc.</a> not the URL which is fine.

Comment: *"keep the raw & in the displayed text"* - Um... no. The ampersand needs to be encoded everywhere.

Comment: `&` is afaik invalid and it should be `&amp;`

Comment: @kitenski Can you show an example. It works [here](http://marco.uctleg.net/resources/encoding.html).

Comment: @Tomalak @thejh Invalid, yes, but most browsers will interpret it correctly. I was focussing on the URL as that's where the question appeared to focus on (reference to `urlencode`). I have updated the answer though.

Comment: @marcog I think my issue is that I am reading the developer title from a database then using rawurlencode which is encoding it to %26, but it appears I need to encode it to &amp; - can I do that in PHP?